# Cannot map single object

Tags: ios, swift, rest, restkit

I am having an issue using RestKit.

I have an endpoint, `items/` where I can `GET` an array of items. Here is a sample return:

```
[
  { item_id: 1 },
  { item_id: 2 },
  { item_id: 3 }
]
```

I can also do something like `items/<item_id>` to get only one item. For example, if I `GET` `items/2` I will get this:

```
{ item_id: 2 }
```

I mapped like this:

```
let itemsResponseMapping: RKObjectMapping = RKObjectMapping(withClass: MyItem.self)
itemsResponseMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["item_id" : "itemId"])

let responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(
        mapping: itemsResponseMapping,
        method: RKRequestMethod.GET,
        pathPattern: "items",
        keyPath: nil,
        statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClass.Successful)
)
objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(responseDescriptor);
```

So, to request I'll do this:

```
RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath(
        ENDPOINT,
        parameters: nil,
        success: {(operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, mapping: RKMappingResult!) -> Void in
            //whatever
        },
        failure: {(operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            //whatever
        }
```

When ENDPOINT is "items" then it succeeds. But when ENDPOINT is "items/2", then I get a `No response descriptors match the response loaded`. If I check `operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString`, then I see the fetch was successful, but the problem is that it's not mapping it.

What am I missing here??

Edit: I should add that I don't own the backend, and the fix should be done in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a second response descriptor with a path pattern of `items/:id` because the simple path pattern doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I just tried this but it didn't work. However, I suspect you're on the correct path here. Is there anything else I could be missing? I haven't found anything about ":id" in the documentation.

Comment: It's in SOCKit docs, and probably on the RestKit wiki page too. I think I have the path syntax correct

Comment: Ok, your solution is correct. It was still failing after your fix due to an unrelated oversight of mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problems lies in different endpoints responses: `items/` returns an **Array of Objects** while `items/<item_id>` returns **a single Object**, no Array. Watch the brackets `[]` from `items/` that does not exists in `items/<item_id>`

You are trying to parse the result of `items/<item_id>` as an array of objects, which is causing the error.

A simple way to fix this is to force enclose the result of a single item to parse it as array. Try converting

```
{ item_id: 2 }
```

Into

```
[ { item_id: 2} ]
```

And your parsing should work in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are absolutely right. However, I'm looking for a fix on the iOS side, since I don't own the backend.

Comment: I see. Am not familiar with `RKObjectManager`, but it seems that somehow you'll need to do that check in your registered mapping strategy. Is there a way to do such check? Maybe force-convert it into an array if it is not?